# .gitignore -- track files AND specific subdirectories of directory

Tags: git, gitignore

Before this is marked as a duplicate out of hand, I've looked at a dozen Stack Overflow questions and none of them have worked for my case.

```
root/
├── trackdir1/          # track directory and its subdirectories
├── trackdir2/          # track directory and its subdirectories
├── ignoreddir/         # ignore all other subdirectories of root
├── .../
└── *                   # keep all FILES within root
```

I have a directory (which is actually a couple directories in, but let's pretend it's `root`).  I want to track all files within `root` and some specific subdirectories of `root`, but to ignore all other subdirectories.

All of the Stack Overflow questions I've looked at did one or the other: included files but ignored subdirectories, or included specific subdirectories and ignored files.

Based on my understanding of .gitignore (which is clearly lacking), I need to make an exception for the files in `root`, exceptions for the specific subdirectories I want to track, and then exclude the files under all subdirectories within root.

```
!/*
!/trackdir1/
!/trackdir1/**
!/trackdir2/
!/trackdir2/**
/*/**
```

However, this pattern still excludes `trackdir1` and `trackdir2`.  I've also tried things like `!/trackdir1` and `!/trackdir1/*`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents of the `.gitignore` file are processed in order, with later instructions overriding earlier ones. So here you have `/*/**` overriding `!/trackdir2/**`, for example.

Simply putting `/*/**` first should work:

```
/*/**
!/*
!/trackdir1/
!/trackdir1/**
!/trackdir2/
!/trackdir2/**
```

Comment: Thank you!  This was driving me crazy.  I thought I had tried reordering it this way, but evidently not.